# Anyway to deal with weird errors while my .net program running?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I made a program, which works fine on my PC without any errors, it also works fine on some office PCs, but it crashes without any describable error on customer's PC and some others.

Crashes are completely random, sometime it may crash and sometimes not.

Crashes are not related with any actions, sometimes it may crash when they just look at the program and wait for crash.

Customers send me this beautiful screens and want me to solve this.
[image]

There you see common error reporting dialog, but not info about Exception.

My program uses Unity Web Player running in **WebBrowser** control. It's always run in background on the hidden tab which becomes visible when needed.

Any ideas how to handle such errors?

Comment: Things are rarely (if ever) random :)  Unfortunately without more information there's very little to go on at all.

Comment: I understand, but it really looks so :( I can't even guess what causes this errors. Are there anyway to enable some advanced error handling to show call stack at least?

Comment: You might want to dump the whole process into a file whenever an uncaught exception raises and then see its state in your IDE.

Comment: Can you add some logging module to trace at which function the application breaks. In case of breakage can application auto email you all the stack trace

Comment: You could potentially have your program run in some kind of diagnostics mode that performs some verbose logging?  Do you have any global "catch-all" exception handlers in your code that could trap any exceptions and log them for you?

Comment: Try to log the exception in the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and see what's going on there.

Comment: But how to catch this errors? I run the form inside Try... catch? Is that what you mean? For unknown reason it doesn't catches such errors.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Waliszko thank you. I will try this, never heard about such things...

Comment: AppDomain.UnhandledException aren't thrown at such errors... just tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first ensure that the environment at your place and that of your customers are identical.

Maybe there're dll or other programs installed at your place (Unity web player as you mentioned for example) or anything in your Registry that may differ.

Else there's no point in getting error on one PC and not on another.

- Make sure all dll are well deployed
- Check your registry,
- Ensure that all related programs are well installed